# Shell command execution via forked process by passing variables through pipes

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork

This is a nothing-to-achieve-special kind of scenario. I want to understand what mistake I"m doing.

**Scenario:**
1. Fork a child process
2. The child process shall execute a shell command (e.g. <s>cat</s> sort a file)
3. The arguments of the shell command are passed from parent process through pipe (e.g. file inputs for the g. <s>cat</s> sort)

I've written the below program <s>but it is displaying the filename instead of printing out the file content.</s> but it is hanging without giving any output on to the screen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){

  int pipefd[2];
  pipe(pipefd);

  //create a pipe before you fork a child process
  pid_t cpid = fork();
  if(cpid < 0){
    perror("Fork");
  }
  else if(cpid == 0){
    printf("This is child process\n");

    close(pipefd[1]);
    close(0);

    dup2(pipefd[0],0);

    execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);

    exit(0);

  }
  else{
    printf("This is parent process\n");
    close(pipefd[0]);

    char *sort_array[] = {"hello", "amigos", "gracias", "hola"};
    for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
      write(pipefd[1],sort_array[i],strlen(sort_array[i]));
      write(pipefd[1], "\n",1);
    }


    int cstatus;
    wait(&cstatus);

  }


}
```

**Update:** 
Original example is not valid. I've updated to sort command.
I'm trying to sort the contents. But the screen is hanging without any output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you use `dup` you simulate child process `stdin` with input of pipe so when you execute `sort` without any argument it's read from `stdin` and it read until it see EOF so you must write to pipe then close it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(){

   int pipefd[2];
   //create a pipe before you fork a child process
   pipe(pipefd);

   pid_t cpid = fork();
   if(cpid < 0){
       perror("Fork");
   } else if(cpid == 0) {
       printf("This is child process\n");

       close(pipefd[1]);
       close(0);

       dup2(pipefd[0],0);

       execlp("sort", "sort", NULL);

       exit(0);

  } else {
      printf("This is parent process\n");
      close(pipefd[0]);

      char *sort_array[] = {"hello", "amigos", "gracias", "hola"};
      for (int i=0; i<4; i++){
          write(pipefd[1],sort_array[i],strlen(sort_array[i]));
          write(pipefd[1], "\n",1);
      }
      close(pipefd[1]);


      int cstatus;
      wait(&cstatus);

    }
}
```

Comment: So silly that I forgot it. Really bad day. It took my whole day out for missing the descriptor close :) . Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

```
pipe(pipefd);  // N.B. failed to check the return value, potential error

//create a pipe before you fork a child process
pid_t cpid = fork();
if (cpid < 0)  // `if` is a language keyword, not a function, space after
{              // opening brace on next line makes reading code easier
    perror("Fork");
}
else if (cpid == 0)
{
    printf("This is child process\n");

    close(pipefd[1]);  // closing "write" end of pipe in child
    close(0);          // closing stdin in child

    dup2(pipefd[0],0); // returned handle is not stored, see https://linux.die.net/man/3/dup2

    execlp("cat", "cat", NULL);  // function prototype is int execlp(const char *file, const char *arg, ...);
                                 // what are you trying to accomplish?

    exit(0);
}
else
{
    printf("This is parent process\n");
    close(pipefd[0]);  // close "read" end of pipe in parent process

    write(pipefd[1], "s.txt", 5);  // write text into pipe

    int cstatus;
    wait(&cstatus);    // wait for ??? something
}
```

Where did you expect the file whose name is passed into the pipe to be opened and written to an output?